# A question with a likely simple answer , pertaining to differentiating $z\bar{z}$ from first principals.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Say we have the complex function $f(z)=z\bar{z}$, I want to show that this is differentiable only at the origin directly without using the Cauchy Riemann equations. ( It's a past exam paper I'm working through).

To do this we should use first principals

$$f'(z)=lim_{h \rightarrow0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$ where h is a complex number ( This is how complex differentiation was defined in class)

$z\bar{z}=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2$

So using this, I think that a derivative from first principals should look like...

$$f'(z)=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(a^2+b^2+h)-a^2-b^2}{h}$$

But using this we get 
$$f'(z)=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{h}=1$$

So either I made a mistake in my first principals or we should use the definition $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$. in which case a first principal argument would look like ;

$$f'(z)=\frac{|z+h|^2-|z|^2}{h}$$ which obviously can,t be differentiated unless z=0 as the denominator other wise will go to zero.

if we take it that z=0 then

$$f'(z)=lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{|h|^2}{h}=\bar{h}$$

So did I do my first principal argument incorrectly when I said that $a^2+b^2=z\bar{z}$ or should we only use $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$ to show it is only differentiable at the origin?

Comment: $f(z+h)$ is not $a^2+b^2+h$. Instead, $f(z+h)=(z+h)(\overline{z+h}) = (z+h)(\bar z + \bar h) = z \bar z + z \bar h + h \bar z + h \bar h$

Comment: Thank you Lee :)

Comment: You could write $f(z)/z = \overline z$ and argue that $f$ can't be differentiable for $z\neq 0$, otherwise $\overline z$ would be. And then you can easily calculate derivative at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lee Mosher said in the comments, $f(z+h) \neq z\overline z + h$, but rather $(z+h)\overline{(z+h)}$.

But, it doesn't seem to hard, because if we write $z = x + yi$ and $h = a + bi$, then \begin{align}f(z+h)-f(z) &= (x + a + (y + b) i) (x + a - (y + b) i) - (x + y i) (x - y i)\\ &= a^2 +b^2+2a x +2 b y\end{align}

and $$\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h} = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + 2ax + 2by}{a + bi}.$$

Now, assume that limit of the RHS exists when $h\to 0$. In particular, it exists when $h$ approaches $0$ along the lines $a = 0$ and $b = 0$, and the limits must be equal. Use it to conclude that $ z = 0$.